# String to JSON to 2D Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, dictionary, httpwebresponse

I am receiving response from httpWebRequest as a string, which is format of JSON. What I would like, is to change this string to json and then, there are two opitons
1) change json to the 2D array
2) change json to dictionary
The point is I want to have easy access to the variables.

This is a string I am receiving:

```
"[{\"Year\":2000,\"Name\":\"Ala\",\"Val\":0.5},{\"Year\":2001,\"Name\":\"Ola\",\"Val\":0.6}... {\"Year\":2004,\"Name\":\"Ela\",\"Val\":0.8}]"
```

So as you can see I could have table with n rows and 3 columns (Year, Name, Val).

This is the code which I use to receive the response

```
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1:5000/");

        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            //send request data in json format 
            streamWriter.Write(jsonData);
        }
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            //take data as string
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Instead of null I will return this array/dictionary.
Which way is better? Someone know how to make it? I feel lost in c#.
Thank you for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to make work with JSON easier you can install [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) package

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 11.0.2
```

Then add `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

Look at this example

```
public class Item
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Val { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = "[{\"Year\":2000,\"Name\":\"Ala\",\"Val\":0.5},{\"Year\":2001,\"Name\":\"Ola\",\"Val\":0.6},{\"Year\":2004,\"Name\":\"Ela\",\"Val\":0.8}]";
        List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(json);

        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Year: {0}; Name: {1}; Val: {2}", item.Year, item.Name, item.Val);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I create a new class `Item` witch will be represents one object from array from your JSON. Then using Newtonsoft.Json deserialize json string to list of items.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me, plus I had problem like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077915/c-sharp-asp-net-could-not-cast-or-convert-from-system-string-to-pagedlist-pagedl , so combinig both solutions I received what I wanted :)

Comment: Great. Glad to have been of help